# Can't assign named pipe name to LPTSTR variable

Tags: c++, winapi, named-pipes

I'm getting used to win32 API shenanigans but it's tiresome, the problem I face this time regards the assignemt of a name of a named pipe, this is what I'm doing:

```
LPTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe");
```

This is [verbatim from MSDN webpages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipe-server-using-overlapped-i-o), and surprise, surprise, this doesn't compile and issues the following error:

> E0144  a value of type "const wchar_t *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "LPTSTR"

Now a cast will solve the assignment but then I get a 109 error, which is, you guessed it, `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE`.

How should I solve this?

Comment: change `LPTSTR` -> `LPCTSTR` - typo ?  Needs to be a pointer to `const` to point to a literal string.  Older MSVC used to allow this but later version are more C++ Standard conforming.

Comment: @RichardCritten well if it is, it's not mine, it from Microsoft, but it seems to make the error go away, I'll have to check if the broken pipe error also goes away.

Comment: you not need declare `lpszPipename` at all. direct pass  `"\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe"` to `CreateNamedPipeW`. the `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` - absolute another problem and question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, despite claims to the contrary, the examples given in the WinAPI documentation are written in (mostly) C, not C++. Also, the use of string literals to initialize non-`const` character pointers is no longer allowed in C++ (since C++11).

So, replace:

```cpp
LPTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe");
```

with:

```cpp
TCHAR lpszPipename[] = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe");
```

*(Whether or not that will fix your `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` is another matter, though!)*

Comment: Note that the code from the example you link compiles as C (albeit with a bunch of warnings about `printf` format mismatches), even in the latest Visual Studio.

Comment: not need this replace of course. possible `LPCTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe");` replace. but this also usually not need. simply `CreateNamedPipeW(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe"),..)`

Comment: here not even need any `const_cast`. api take pointer to constant string. 2 errors in original code - use variable *lpszPipename* (for what it need ?) and wrong declare it - simply change `LPTSTR ` to `LPCTSTR`

Answer (score 2):

`LPTSTR` is the non-const version. You're trying to acquire a non-const pointer to a string literal.

This used to be valid C++ (it still is valid C, hence the sample), but it was very dangerous, so they made illegal in C++11. You either want:

```
wchar_t const* lpszPipename = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe";
```

or

```
wchar_t pipename[] = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe";
```

Comment: I would really prefer that microsoft docs weren't so full of gremlins, but this would be my second choice ;)

Comment: I was using `const_cast<TCHAR*>`

Comment: @anastaciu instead of using a nasty cast, just use the array syntax. If the code tries to mutate a string literal, no cast can save you.

Comment: @anastaciu keep in mind that the array is going to have a different life-time than a string literal.

Comment: The broken pipe problem remains, the issue must be elsewhere, I'll have to debug this tomorrow, thanks, and @AdrianMole. One last question, what do you think of Richard's LPCTSTR solution? it does work and seems like a clean replacement.

Comment: @anastaciu `LPCTSTR` is defined as `const TCHAR*`. You can use that if you don't want to spell out the type. But don't use the generic macros, they are outdated. Use the wide-string versions: `LPCWSTR p = L"..."`.

Comment: Well the problem was unrelated, as we established. This is an overlaped IO server that receives messages from several clients and I was returning to the main cycle before treating the message which lead to the client pipe bieng closed before issuing the answer, again thanks for your answer, all the answers are correct, I accepted the one that had more votes (at the time of acceptance), it could be any one of them, so sorry about that ;) you where very helpful as usual.

Comment: @anastaciu glad we could help!

Comment: *"it's not legal now"* - That's not correct. It's still [legal C](https://godbolt.org/z/sxqqj3Tc6) code.

Comment: @IInspectable you're right. The question is tagged with C++ though. I will add the remark. Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 2):

[`CreateNamedPipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea) take pointer to **constant** string ( LPCSTR or LPCWSTR) in place pipe name. so and do direct

```
CreateNamedPipe(TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe"), ..)
```

i not view any reason for

```
LPCTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe");
CreateNamedPipe(lpszPipename , ..)
```

however if by some reason use `lpszPipename` - it must be declared as pointer to constant string. `LPCTSTR lpszPipename` instead `LPTSTR lpszPipename`

---

possible and next solution - declare in global scope

```
static const WCHAR gPipename[] = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe";
```

and use it, on binary level `CreateNamedPipeW(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe"), ..)` and `CreateNamedPipeW(gPipename, ..)` produce the same code

Comment: Well, I ended up using LPCSTR since I'm not a fan of string literals in function arguments, thanks for your help, [I solved the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67863916/cant-assign-named-pipe-name-to-lptstr-variable#comment119962930_67863936) and it was unrelated as established. All the answers where correct, so I accepted the one that had more votes at the time, thanks again for your help.

Comment: @anastaciu - *I'm not a fan of string literals in function arguments* why ? what sense do temporary assignment ? by fact you do `x = y, z = x`  when can just `z = y`

Comment: Maybe you're right, it's a habit, all my string literals I usually save as constants stored away in some interface, so that's where it comes from I guess.

Comment: In this case is particularly helpful because this pipe is to be used by both clients and server so it avoids errors by way of typos in the string.

Comment: @anastaciu i be declare `static const WCHAR gPipename[] = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe";` in global scope and use this